# Cannot append to file I created?

Tags: linux, permissions, nas, file-permissions

I have this WD MyBook NAS with some kind of PowerPC Linux on it.  When I log in to the device, I can't seem to *append* to files that I create myself.

Example session is like so:

```
adib@constantinople:~/Downloads/test$ ls -lah
total 128K
drwxrwxrw- 2 adib share 64K Dec 19 20:36 .
drwxrwxrw- 6 adib share 64K Dec 19 20:36 ..
adib@constantinople:~/Downloads/test$ echo blah > test.txt
adib@constantinople:~/Downloads/test$ ls -lah
total 192K
drwxrwxrw- 2 adib share 64K Dec 19 20:37 .
drwxrwxrw- 6 adib share 64K Dec 19 20:36 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 adib share   5 Dec 19 20:37 test.txt
adib@constantinople:~/Downloads/test$ echo blah 2 >> test.txt
-sh: test.txt: Permission denied
adib@constantinople:~/Downloads/test$ uname -a
Linux constantinople 2.6.32.11-svn70860 #1 Thu May 17 13:32:51 PDT 2012 ppc GNU/Linux
adib@constantinople:~/Downloads/test$ lsattr
-----------------e- ./test.txt
adib@constantinople:~/Downloads/test$
```

In the sample session above, I've created a file `test.txt` using `echo` which was created successfully. The file's permissions also looks okay. However I can't seem to *append* to the file as the next `echo` command fails with a `Permission denied` error.

What kind of permissions that I'm missing here?

Comment: The disk is not full, is it? What does 'df -h .' show and can you echo into a second file?

Comment: No, disk is not full. Yes, I can echo to a second file or even a third file. Just echoing to the same file doesn't work.